# Get Max Date Using CAML Query From alist

Tags: sharepoint, caml

how can i get  max Date and Min Date from a list Date Column

Comment: Thank you for this good answer but if i want to you GroupBy Tag to do this , how can i implement this soluation

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516073/max-query-using-caml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force approach is to create two queries that will retrieve the list content sorted by date asc and desc. I know that this sucks but at least you can move on with you project and refine the query later on.

If only it was possible to retrieve top 1 then it might even work in production.

Comment: Thank you for this good answer but if i want to you GroupBy Tag to do this , how can i implement this soluation