# Accessing last record in a sharepoint list via CAML query

Tags: sharepoint, caml

i ve some problem in accessing last record from sharepoint list through CAML query,can any one help me in this regrad;i have a sample list called 'MainHeads' which contains the information like HeadID,Category,and headName....

Mehboob
Pakistan

Answer (score 5):

```
<View>
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
<Query>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>
</View>
```

Comment: An alternative could be the ID Column, which (AFAIK) is also available on every item.

Answer (score 3):

```
<View> 
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit> 
<Query> 
   <OrderBy> 
      <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> 
   </OrderBy> 
</Query> 
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516073/max-query-using-caml/1265240#1265240) I gave to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516073/max-query-using-caml), I would suggest the following query:

```
SPListItem lastItem;

try
{
    using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(sSiteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList objList = objWeb.Lists["MainHeads"];

            SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
            objQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='HeadID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>";
            objQuery.Folder = objList.RootFolder;

            // Execute the query against the list
            SPListItemCollection colItems = objList.GetItems(objQuery);

            if (colItems.Count > 0)
            {
                lastItem = colItems[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}

return lastItem;
```

This assumes that you are executing the CAML in code.  IF not, see [F. Aquino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187126/f-aquino)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671664/accessing-last-record-in-a-sharepoint-list-via-caml-query/1868910#1868910).